# Iterate through query set and compare the query set

Tags: django, django-models

I want to compare elements of queryset using their fields and create a new list of Sorted Objects.
exam: 
1)stud = Student.objects.all()
2)stud.objects.sort()
the sort function will compare each item in the queryset and sort them using the sgpa, and attendance fields

```
class StudentManager(models.Manager):
    def Sort(self):

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    sgpa = models.IntegerField()
    attendance = models.FloatField()

    objects = StudentManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by and it will not need `StudentManager`:

```
Student.objects.order_by('sgpa', 'attendance')
```

Comment: Is there anyway to compare each element

Comment: under the hood, in database layer elements are compared.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Student.objects.all().order_by('sgpa').order_by('attendance')
```

If you use an "-" like ".order_by('-sgpa')", it will be sorted in descending order.

Comment: I want to have a custom sorting method using a for loop or iterate

Comment: I think the better way is in the query, but, you can try this:

import operator
d = Student.objects.all()

sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1, 2))

In this solution, the number 1 represent the "sgpa", you can add more like this:

operator.itemgetter(1) where 1 is sgpa and 2 is attendance.